# how to resize img in React

Tags: reactjs

```
 render() {
   <img className="photo" src={"/public/love"} />

 }
```

I have a css file linked to it and it still isn't working

```
 .photo {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px; 
 }
```

How can you resize an img in react?Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

This is **another way** to give the size to the image in the latest **Reactjs** direct in the code. you can also use the classes to target the image.

```
<img src='imagepath.jpg' width={250} height={250} alt='Large Pizza' />
```

Answer (score 14):

I am not sure if the import of css is wrong there something else that is causing the issue.
Working [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-cray-32z90)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import panda from "./images/panda.png";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <img alt="panda" className="photo" src={panda} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

styles.css

```
.photo {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use the proper jsx syntax.

```
render() {
    return <img className="photo" src={ require('/public/love') } />;
}
```

Otherwise the css looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try inline styling like this:

```
<img className="photo" src={"/public/love"} style={{height:100, width:100}} />
```